# Why, if I use SUMIF with dates, is the result 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am using `SUMIF` with dates.

[image: Screenshot of my SUMIF issue.]

As you see, the result is 0. Why? What should I use instead of `SUMIF`, if that is not the correct function?

Comment: What happens if you use DATEVALUE(E1)?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Reproduction of question scenario]

I've tried implementing exactly what you typed in Excel as you can see, and it works (the cell shows 9.6). I'm guessing that your cells A2:A11 may not be in the correct "date format". Check the cell format, make sure it is the same as your cell format in E1,F1...etc.

---

For anyone not familiar with the SUMIF function:

[SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) (links to microsoft) works as such:

```
foreach element in range {
    if element == criteria {
        sum = sum + corresponding element in sum_range
    }
}
return sum
```

Note that if `sum_range` does not match `range`, `sum_range` is extended to match the same number of cells covered in `range`.

---

### A bit of Background with Dates

Dates are basically integer numbers of days from a reference point, and so must be in the correct format for Excel to interpret correctly.

What you see on display as a date isn't the underlying integer (you can view that integer by changing a "date formatted" cell to a "number" cell). Excel just interprets the numbers and displays them as dates. Hence, to compare two dates, the underlying integers must be the same.

The easiest way to do this is to make sure the cell formats are the same, then ensure the cell contents are the same.